# android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException into AsyncTask

Tags: java, android

I have the following class:

```
class CargaImgsParaAmpliar extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Bitmap> {

        final ProgressDialog progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(imagen.this);

        protected void onPreExecute() {
            progressDialog.setTitle("");
            progressDialog.setMessage("Cargando Imagen...");
            progressDialog.show();
        }

        protected Bitmap doInBackground(Void... params) {
            Bitmap mIcon1 = null;
            URL url_value;
            try {
                url_value = new URL(StrUrl);
                mIcon1 = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(url_value.openConnection().getInputStream());
            } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }           
            return mIcon1;
        }

        protected void onPostExecute(Bitmap imagen) {
            m_imageView.setImageBitmap(urlImageToBitmap(StrUrl));
            progressDialog.dismiss();
        }       
    }
```

I am doing internet discharge processes within AsyncTask and it still gives me the exception `android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException`.

How can I fix this isse?

Comment: And from where you are executing this AsyncTask?

Comment: Within the method onDoubleTap that is within the class GestureListener.

Comment: can you post `urlImageToBitmap` code. Chances are its calling the server. `OnPostExecute` runs on the UITHread.

Comment: `code`public Bitmap urlImageToBitmap(String urlImage) {
   Bitmap mIcon1 = null;
   URL url_value;
   try {
    url_value = new URL(urlImage);
    mIcon1 = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(url_value.openConnection().getInputStream());
   } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
   }catch (IOException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
   }   
   return mIcon1;
  }`code`

Answer (score 2):

It seems to me that `urlImageToBitmap` accesses the network but is executed from `onPostExecute` (which is run on the UI task).

And you don't seem to be doing anything with `imagen` parameter in `onPostExecute`. So the image retrieved in `doInBackground` is basically lost.

Comment: Yes, in this method I connect to internet again.
Perfect, thanks for your help, I'll call from doInBackground.